# How to know if SP 2013 Task is complete?

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, tasks

How can you tell if a task is complete once it is assigned by the workflow? I have "Assign a Task" in my SP Designer workflow, and I don't want the workflow to move forward until the task is completed, rather Approved or Rejected.

Is there a certain Task Content Type that has to be filled (Task Outcome?)

Comment: you can go to the workflow status page and it will say the tasks and who is assigned to them and if they have completed the tasks or not. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I saw that, I guess I'm trying to figure out what makes a task "complete". I customized my form and I put the task outcome field in there that I signified as the "Outcome Field". I think the workflow is being held up because it is waiting on the Task to be completed.

Comment: Approving or Rejecting, which are task outcomes. When you choose a task outcome, the task becomes complete.

Comment: Does that have to be done on the task form? I placed the Outcome Choice field on my list form and even when i pick "approve" it doesn't move on in the workflow.

Comment: That's part of the InfoPath form that SPD generates. Not sure the nuts and bolts of it, but I assume that it completes the task as well as documents the task outcome.

Answer (score 0):

In the Assign Task Window, there is a setting to "wait for task completion". I think it should work for your scenario.

Here is an [MSDN article](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/understanding-task-actions-in-sharepoint-designer) explains that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have that setting turned on. I guess that's what is confusing me. I have the Task Outcome field chosen as "Approved", but it seems that the workflow is not moving on.

Comment: I read in the article about the Variable: Outcome and created an "Update Item" to see what Outcome it would report. I didn't get anything.

Comment: I just tested this. Steps are `step 1: Assign a task and settings shown in image` and `step2: log the response`. My workflow waited until I approve the task and log the response after that. Please let me know if I miss any of your cases.

Comment: Since I have a custom content type that is applied to my task list, would I need to assign it under the Outcome Options, or leave it as Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013). The parent type of my site content type is Workflow Task.

Comment: I left the Workflow Task as it is.